# How to manually install a package in racket?

Tags: racket, packets

How can I manually install a package in racket (that is without relying on raco)? Is that possible?

I installed the minimal racket distribution and want to manually add the packages in question (such as `xrepl` which doesn't seem to come by default).

I'm on CentOS and I have no root privileges (the installation is in a private directory).

Comment: Would `raco pkg install --scope user` work?

Comment: @GregHendershott In any case I get `call-with-file-lock/timeout: contract violation
  expected: (>=/c 0.0)
  given: -1202590842.0` and then I believe a traceback. Google isn't very forthcoming on what this means, which is why I was hoping to get around that by manually setting up the package. All I can assume is that it is something remotely related to the NFS protocol (as I had this happen to me a few times during the compilation stage).

Comment: On mailing list too... what version of Racket is this?

Comment: @JohnClements 6.1.1 the minimal distribution

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm not sure I understand the permissions issue you're having, you could try `raco pkg install --scope user`.

Anyway, you can use `raco pkg install --link <dir>` to install locally. (Just like what people do when they're developing a package locally.)

So for example:

1. `cd ~/src`
2. `git clone path/to/foo`

   (Or get the package source into `~/src/foo` some other way. By "package source" I mean there should be an `info.rkt` in `~/src/foo`.)
3. `raco pkg install --link foo`

If the `foo` package has any dependencies, than `raco pkg install` will offer to get and install them, too. Normally this would be handy. But since you're having connection or permission problems, I imagine you'll want to answer No. Instead, do this manual install for each of the deps, then retry this one. (Obviously if there are many deps, this is inconvenient, which is one of the benefits of using a package manager when you are able to.)

Comment: Thanks, I keep getting that problem, can't work out if it's permissions or NFS related, but I'm sure that will still come in handy if/when I get around it.

Comment: If you ask about that on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/racket-users one of the Racket devs might be able to help. Some are also on #racket IRC.

Comment: By the way, in step 3 you could simply do `raco link <dir> && raco setup <dir>`. That links and builds the collection, without any package system stuff. But you'd need to figure out any missing deps yourself.

Comment: I can't do anything that involves `raco pkg install`, even typing in just `raco pkg install` results in said error, very frustrating :/